# Showing that $4x^2 + 6xy + 4y^2 > 0$ unless $x=y=0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

> Exercise 1.16.b: Using the fact that
>
> $x^2 + 2xy + y^2 = (x + y)^2 \geq 0$,
>
> show that
>
> $4x^2 + 6xy + 4y^2 > 0$ unless x and y are both $0$.

The provided solution is a proof by contradiction, but I want to make sure that my direct proof is also right:

From $x^2 + 2xy + y^2 \geq 0$ it follows that $3x^2 + 6xy + 3y^2 \geq 0$.

Since $3x^2 + 6xy + 3y^2 \geq 0$ and $4x^2 + 6xy + 4y^2 = 3x^2 + 6xy + 3y^2 + x^2 + y^2$,
it suffices to show that $x^2 + y^2 > 0$.

Both $x$ and $y$ cannot be $0$ (specified in assignment), so it is obvious that $x^2 + y^2 > 0$.

Is this approach also correct?

Comment: $x \ne 0$ and $y \ne 0$ does not imply $x^2 + y^2 > 0$, e.g.: $x = \sqrt{2}$ and $y = \sqrt{-2}$.

Comment: You've got to at least remark on the fact that squares of reals are non-negative.

Comment: @Deepak the OP didn't specified that $x$ and $y$ are reals.

Comment: @TiagoCavalcanteTrindade The 'use this' part implies that we are only using the reals as it only holds in the reals

Comment: Your proof is fine. You could slightly improve it by showing noting why $x^2+y^2$ is positive (since squares of reals are nonnegative), and it’s slightly less confusing to show that and then add that to the $3x^2…$ term instead of subtracting and saying “it suffices”. It’s better to solve backwards, write forwards.

Comment: Your proof is fine but can be shorter: $4x^2 + 6xy + 4y^2 = 3(x+y)^2+x^2+y^2 \ge 0$; moreover, since it's a sum of three squares, it's zero iff all terms are zero.